# Mac App Store app can't be uninstalled, won't finish installing

Tags: macos, applications, install, mac-appstore

So I went to download and install McSolitaire thinking it might be a fun game. Well, something went wrong during the install process. Now I've got a half-downloaded app in my Applications and the Purchases tab encourages me to re-install it, noting in red that an `error has occurred`. Deleting the app from Applications and returning to the App Store causes the app to reappear in Applications, still with the small slider indicating `still copying`.

At this point I just want it to be installed or gone. I don't really care if I play Solitaire using the app.

What do I do now?

Some screenshots for the discerningly minded:
[image: What it shows in Finder]

and
[image: The App Store]

Clicking install says:
[image: Useless error message]

and below that ...
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me you should contact apple support.

I can think of several diagnostics here.

1. Is it apple ID specific?
2. Is your DNS servers having trouble or not local enough so apple knows where you are and which CDN node to use? Make sure you use the ones from your ISP.
3. Lastly, you may want to test with another user account, and make sure the app store functions correctly there.
4. If you can get away with it, does it work in Safe Mode? (holding down shift at boot)
5. When you run a traceroute, is the latency really high? What about speed?
6. What OS are you using? Snow Leopard, Lion or Mountain Lion. Mountain Lion probably has a much more integrated app store, and it might work better for you. (major surgery though.)

Comment: Mountain Lion, not a latency issue, everything else works really well, and it's just the one. I haven't tried alternate apple IDs, and I haven't contacted them, as it's just an annoyance to date.

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce the issue... I installed the app just fine from the App Store on my mac.

I would say, cancel the install from the App Store and just [download the app directly from the developer](http://www.pcv-soft.com/mcsolitaire/product_mcsolitaire_mac.html). You can just copy the app to your Applications folder.

Try this:

1. Quit the App Store
2. Open the **Applications** folder (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in the Finder), locate **McSolitaire**, and delete it. (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> or drag to the Trash).
3. Go to your home directory (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in the Finder) and go to the App Store cache folder (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, then enter: `Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/`)
4. Select all the files and delete (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> or drag to the Trash)
5. Reopen the App Store and see if the error still appears.
6. [Download the app directly from the developer](http://www.pcv-soft.com/mcsolitaire/product_mcsolitaire_mac.html) and install it by dragging out of the Disk Image and into the Applications folder.

Comment: You got me about 80% there, it's no longer in Applications, nor does it show up there when pressing "Install" (as seen above) but it's still showing in Purchases and still refuses to attempt to install. There's no way to make it go poof is there?

Comment: I suppose I should just "Hide Purchase" at this point.

Comment: Strangely enough I must have hid the purchase and now can't get it *back*. I never use the App Store, I download and install almost all apps manually...